# SVN: How to list author, date and comments from svn log

Tags: windows, svn, commit

I am using SVN on Windows 10 machine. I want to list `Author`, `Date` and `Comment` of all commits within a date range. So I want to report 1 line per commit and each line has 3 columns.  How can I do that?

I want to be able to copy that report and paste in Excel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Nohow. You can't change format of [log output](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html#idm10272) in pure SVN, you can only disable (`-q` option) log-message in separate line(s)

## Longer answer

Because svn log have always single (documented) format of output and [`-r` option](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.revision) accept date as parameters you can write appropriate log-command and post-process results (in standard human-readable form or in [xml-output](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.xml))

## Long answer

If generating different custom reports from SVN-repositories is your long-running regular task, you can *to think* (at least) about using Mercurial (with hgsubversion) as interface for processing data. With HG you'll have
- transparent access to original SVN-repos
- full power of templating and revsets for extracting and manipulating of data for your needs and requirements

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called the Subversion Webview. These are third party mostly free to use web view of your repository where you can filter out commints like the following:
[image: Web View Showing the recent history from my repository]

You can either filter there in the view or copy it in excel and add a filter yourself.

Hope this helps.